# Updating jar version in script based on jar built by maven

Tags: maven

I have a maven based project which builds a jar with a version say, myproject-1.0.jar
I have a shell script that runs the jar and does other processing work.
Now i am facing an issue where i need to manually update the jar version in script everytime i update the version in maven.
Is there a way where i can update the jar name with version in the script ?
I understand that i can remove the version from the jar or write code in the script to fetch the latest version, but i would like to know if maven can update the script file content.

Comment: Have added a possible solution. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Maven, there is a feature called resource filtering. Using it, Maven copies the shell script (it must be located in `src/main/resources` folder) into your output classes and translate the resource during that copy, interpreting the property.

Create a placeholder in the shell script `${version}` or `${project.version}` (new maven) corresponds to version of the jar file.

In your `pom.xml`, add below

```
<resources>
<resource>
  <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  <includes>
     <include>*.sh</include>
  </includes>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

Resource Filter should pick the version info from runtime and replace in the shell placeholder.

The filtering has a lot of customization available, including `<outputDirectory>` to have the filtered resource copied outside the bundled jar.